# update de formulario con request en laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tengo Este formulario que actualiza la tabla usuario, pero me lanza este error:

MENSAJE DEL ERROR:  Creating default object from empty value

[image: Formulario para actualizar la tabla]

EL Codigo del Formulario:

```
    <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase">Formulario de Edicion</h1>

    {!!Form::model($usuarios, ['route'=> ['admin.update', '$usuarios->id'], 'method'=>'PUT'])!!}

        <div class="form-group">

        {!!Form::token()!!}

        <div class="form-group">

            {!!Form::label('nombre', 'Nombre', ['class' => 'awesome'])!!}
            {!!Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingresa tu nombre'])!!}

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            {!!Form::label('email', 'Email', ['class' => 'awesome'])!!}
            {!!Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese su correo'])!!}

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            {!!Form::label('password', 'Passwork', ['class' => 'awesome'])!!}
            {!!Form::password('password', ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ingrese su passwork'])!!}

        </div>
        <br>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::submit('Actualizar', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
        </div>
    </div>
```

EL Codigo del Controlador:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $users = User::find($id);
        $users->name = $request->name;
        $users->email = $request->email;
        $users->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $users->save();
        return redirect('admin')->with('mensaje', 'Usuario actualizado correctamente');
    }
```

---

Gracias por responder, sigue dando el mismo error aun haciendolo asi:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $users = User::find($id);
    $users->name =$request->get('name');
    $users->email = $request->get('email');
    $users->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
    $users->save();
    return redirect('admin')->with('mensaje', 'Usuario actualizado correctamente');
}
```

Comment: Para acceder a los parámetros del request necesitas hacerlo de esta forma `$request->get('name')` ese es tu error.

Comment: puedes agregar una captura del error

Comment: Gracias por responder, sigue dando el mismo error aun haciendolo asi: $users = User::find($id);
    $users->name =$request->get('name');
    $users->email = $request->get('email');
    $users->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
    $users->save();
    return redirect('admin')->with('mensaje', 'Usuario actualizado correctamente');

Answer (score 2):

veo dos problemas.

1. en tu vista: `{!!Form::model($usuarios, ['route'=> ['admin.update', '$usuarios->id'], 'method'=>'PUT'])!!}`. `$usuarios->id` está entrecomillas, por lo que cuando haces el PUT, no es con el id del usuario sino que con el valor `"$usuarios->id"`.
2. Debido al problema anterior, tu variable `$users` es `NULL` por lo cual no puedes editar sus propiedades, lanzando el error que indicas: **Creating default object from empty value**

Específicamente, este error se refiere a lo que expongo antes, tratar de modificar una variable nula, como si de un objeto se tratase, por ejemplo:

```
→ cat null.php
<?php
$obj = NULL;

$obj->a = 'a';
$obj->b = 'b';

→ php null.php
PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in <path>/null.php on line 5
```

saludos

Comment: Muchísimas gracias brother... ese era el error. no lo estaba asimilando como  un entero... por las comillas..

Comment: De nada Gali no olvides marcar como aceptada la respuesta

Comment: Donde esta esa opción? no la visualizo...

Comment: Aca mismo, debes aceptar mi respuesta